# How does one calculate CPU utilization programmatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, benchmarking

I have a benchmarking program that calculates the time (in milliseconds and ticks), for a persistance to Entity Framework 4.0.  Is there a way to calculate CPU load ?  I am guessing that I would need to query Windows to find out my CPU frequency, how many cores, etc.  Does this sound right ?  If so, what part of the .NET framework relates to querying the system ?  I am guessing System.Diagnostics ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Do you need to measure the total cpu time on the system, or per process?

Comment: Hey Sander!  I want the utilization for my process/thread...a performance counter for CPU load on the system would give erroneous data due to other processes running on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a PerformanceCounter (for the System load).

Or, better:

```
var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var span = p.TotalProcessorTime;
```

You will have to relate that to wall-time to get a percentage. Also see UserProcessorTime.

---

Edit:

On second thought, if you want to benchmark wouldn't you rather measure just elapsed time from executing a piece of code, eg the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class?

Comment: You would think that the total processor time spent in the process would get successively larger as the loop executes, but sometimes a LATER operation shows less total time the an earlier one!  What's the reason for that ?

Comment: @Scott, I cannot reproduce that. Check the basics, like TimeSpan.__Total__Milliseconds (not Milliseconds).

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1(v=VS.90).aspx

Seems to be what you're looking for

This code I found may help:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
PerformanceCounter oPerf1 = new PerformanceCounter();
oPerf1.CategoryName = "Processor";
oPerf1.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
oPerf1.InstanceName = "0";
int I;
for (I = 0; (I <= 100); I++) {
    SomeListBox.Items.Add(oPerf1.NextValue);
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

Comment: +1 because no one uses perf mon but it is so very awesome. There are TONS of stuff to monitor.

Answer (score 2):

You can get at the Performance Counters data, but it's surely got to be better to use a profiling tool.  CPU utilisation isn't in itself a useful measurement.  You want to know which are the slowest bits of your code compared to other bits, and which are fast but called too many times, etc.